# Problema con los permisos en phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

Estoy usando *phpMyAdmin* como gestor de bases de datos en mi servidor *Centos*, pese a tener permitido el acceso a todos, en el archivo **phpMyAdmin.conf**. Tengo desactivado *SELinux*.

Al intentar entrar desde mi navegador me da el siguiente error:

> Forbidden : You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server

Como curiosidad, poniendo el servidor local tampoco tengo acceso desde *localhost*.

¿Es compatible *phpMyAdmin 4.7.0* con la versión *PHP 7.1.4*?

Anteriormente con *PHP 5.5*  funcionaba correctamente.

Las versiones de las tecnologías que uso:

- *Centos 7.3*.
- *PHP 7.1.4*.
- *PHP MyAdmin 4.7.0*.
- *Apache 2.4.6*.
- *MySql 10*.

**phpMyAdmin.conf**:

```html
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Comment: Eso parece un problema de permisos en los archivos y directorios. Ese directorio debería tener permisos de `755` y pertenecer al usuario y/o grupo que ejecuta `httpd`.

Comment: ¿Y si descomentas y cambias: `Require ip 10.1.1.5` y `Allow from 10.1.1.5` (sustituye `10.1.1.5` por la IP  del servidor donde está la bd).

Comment: Sigo con el mismo problema Forbidden

Doy permiso 755 al directorio /usr/share/phpMyAdmin chmod -R 755 /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/

Doy permiso de acceso al usuario/grupo apache en Centos7

chown -R apache:apache /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

Cambio la ip en la configuración para un user local y nada pongo mi ip remota nada...

Esto perdido,ya no se que mas puedo hacer para obtener los permisos apropiado para poder acceder al gestor de bases phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin 4.7.0 soporta PHP 5.5 a 7.1 y MySQL 5.5 o superior, por lo tanto eso no es problema.

Te recomendaría que mirases que te está diciendo Apache en sus logs. Abre el fichero `/etc/httpd.conf` y busca la directiva `LogFile`, seguramente sea el directorio `/var/log/httpd`

Una vez estés en el directorio de los logs haz un `cat *.log` y pega por aquí que es lo que te dice.